# Error __DIR__ con include

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en una web y quería usar `__DIR__` para traer la conexión de la base de datos, pero resulta que al usarlo toda la web queda en blanco, porque puede pasar esto?

```
<?php
include __DIR__.'../include/cont_db.php';
?>
```

Comment: Que versión de php utilizas?

Comment: Uso PHP Version 7.3.0

Comment: Bueno, no entiendo el por que debes utilizar '__DIR__' cuando puedes incluir e fichero sin el, pero lo que te puedo decir es que esa constante se añadio en **PHP 5.3**, con lo que si tienes una version anterior no podra funcionar, además de que la respuesta que te han dado no esta mal, por que '__DIR__' es igual que utilizar la función 'dirname(__FILE__)', te lo pongo por comentarios por que no sé si es la solución a tu problema.

Comment: Y cual es el motivo de utilizar esta constante? (si es que se puede saber)

Comment: Por seguridad o tengo un concepto erróneo respecto a eso?

Comment: Puedes hacer solo un `echo` de `__DIR__` para ver que te devuelve?

Comment: si hago un `echo` me devuelve la ruta del archivo `srv/http/sistema/include/cont_db.php`

Comment: Puedes añadir estar líneas antes del `include` y decirnos si muestra algún error?

```ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```